# Not Able to Connect to Router using WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, 802.11n, 802.11ac

I have a laptop which is a few years old now. We have recently got a new Netgear ADSL2 modem/router for work which says on its box that it has two WiFi interfaces:
802.11n 2.4GHz (3x3) & 802.11AC 5GHz (4x4)

The problem is that my laptop wireless card which is **802.11a/b/g/n 2x2** capable can see both my router's 2.4 & 5 networks but when I connect, I have no internet connection. Doing an ipconfig reveals that it can't get an IP from the router's DHCP server, it only shows 169.254.x.x range.

My DHCP service is fine because when I use the Ethernet LAN, it can get IP from the router.

Is it because my wireless card is not compatible with my wireless router?

Comment: Do you have any other wifi devices you can test with?

Comment: @Paul the other laptops in the office can connect using Wi-Fi. It's only mine that has problem connecting using wifi. That being said, I can connect my laptop to my home wifi network.